# lookup algorithm for finding a shell command

Tags: command-line, scripts

In my example, I am going to use the shell command "rake".

What is the lookup sequence Ubuntu uses to find what to do when rake is invoked? e.g. does it look for a path specified in .bash_profile, does it look some place else, etc.

Comment: huh? you need to explain a bit more.  Are you talking about "tab completion?"  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_completion

Comment: Im talking about environment variables, path environment variables, and whatever else the kernel does to find out what to do with a command @MattH

Comment: It is not the kernel, it's simply the shell (in your case, `bash`). Of course it does some system calls so the kernels is involved too but the shell is an userspace program (which means that it is not part of the kernel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume you installed it through `rvm`.
As you said, your `PATH` is modified by `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.

What the shell does is very simple, it looks at your command and splits it with the spaces and look for the first word (in you case, `rake`).
Then it looks at the `PATH` environment variable (see its value with `echo $PATH`) which contains different directories separated by semicolons (`:`). It splits it with the semicolons and then iterate through every directory to see if there is a file that you have the rights to execute. When it finds it, the shell executes it giving the rest of the words as arguments.

In the case of `rvm`, you should have `/home/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374@global/bin` in you `PATH`. It should find an executable called `rake` which then executes an executable called `rake` in `/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/bin` which run `/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake.rb` (your version may vary).

Comment: Yeah this explanation is exactly what I was looking for